# Is it to safe to charge my lithium ion battery at 1C?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm making a 3S1P battery pack, and I wanted to understand if there was any reason why I wouldn't be able to charge my batteries at 1C (around 3400mA charging rate.)

I'm using the [Panasonic NCR18650GA](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0481/9678/0183/files/60f5bf9a9fbf95001ac60005-GA6W.pdf?v=1626883833).

In the datasheet, at standard temperatures, the charging rate called out is 1675mA (about 1/2 C.) If I'm monitoring the temperature of my batteries, and making sure that it doesn't get too hot, could I increase the charging rate without there being a high risk of a fire?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a blessing here for charging batteries at out-of- spec rates. On page 12 of the datasheet, page 14 of the PDF, however, there is a statement about the (absolute?) maximum charging current of an NCR18650G-H0SVA battery (3,35A/cell). Still, 1.675A is the "recommended maximum charging current".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet says what the charging limits are.

According to datasheet charging can be done within all the limits given that are safe. 3.35A is safe but it will degrade the battery faster and thus it won't perform according to specs that are given at the nominal charging current.

So while possible, another thing is whether it should be done as it exceeds nominal usage the batteries are intended for. If you need better batteries, buy better batteries.